# dúvida sobre o select no css

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de criar um espaçamento nos option do meu select, alguém pode me explicar como

```
<form method= "POST" class="mb-0" action="includes-site/enviar.php" id="formcadastro" >
    <div>
        <label>Primeiro Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control"id="nome">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" onkeypress="mascara(this)">
    </div>
    <label>Qual Melhor forma de atendimento?</label>
    <select name="atendimento" id="Atendimento" class= "form-control">

    <option value="" disabled selected>Clique e Selecione</option>
    <option value="WhatsApp">Whatsapp</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
    <option value="Ligação">Ligação</option>

    </select>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn--block mt-10" value="enviar">
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="titulo" value="<?php echo $tit;?>">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Que tipo de espaçamento você precisa? Poderia dar um exemplo de como gostaria que ficasse?

Answer (score 1):

use "padding".

```css
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

superior, direito, inferior e esquerdo é a ordem das regras de padding.

Se não quiser abreviar, use:

```css
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
```

Lembrando, você pode alterar o valor de "5px" pro que quiser. Em porcentagem, pixels, "em", todas as opções disponíveis.

Comment: Entendi, mas estou com dúvida de como chamar a classe no style, pode me explicar por favor?

Comment: Claro. 
Use:

option{
     *insira aqui o código*
}

Comment: Como "option" não é class nem id, não precisa nem de "." nem de "#" pra chamá-la.

Comment: Você também pode inserir uma class="option", mas acredito ser redundante, já que você consegue fazer sem :)

Answer (score 0):

O **padding** é o mais recomendado neste caso, ele vai criar um espaço interno. O importante é que você defina para todos os lados, senão acaba jogando o conteúdo da  para um lugar que não deseja.

```
padding: 5px;
```

ooooooooou, você pode fazer para todos um por um:

```
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
```

Comment: Isso não funciona

Comment: Pode me mandar o seu código então?

Comment: Com padding é que não é amigo, agora como faz eu não sei, vc poderia ter testado seu código antes de postar. Responder qq coisa na ajuda, principalmente se não funciona...

Answer (score 0):

**Correção:** Funciona apenas no `<Select>`

Você também pode usar uma classe (ou ID) no  e manipular o padding ou margin do option, tipo:

```
select {
 padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Isso não funciona

Comment: Editei... Após testar percebi que funciona apenas no Select

Answer (score -1):

Use padding nos options

**No CSS**

```
.option {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**No HTML**

```
<option class="option" value="" disabled selected>Clique e Selecione</option>
<option class="option" value="WhatsApp">Whatsapp</option>
<option class="option" value="Email">Email</option>
<option class="option" value="Ligação">Ligação</option>
```

Comment: Isso não funciona

Comment: @Geremias, poste a sua solução para ajudar o cara

Answer (score -2):

De uma maneira rápida você pode usar a [tag br](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) `<br>`, ou pode usar [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) para adicionar `margin` ou `padding` dependendo do que quer fazer.

Edit:

Não notei que era espaçamento entre as opções, não é possível usar o `<br>` entre `option`

Sorry :/

Comment: tentei usar o br e não funcionou, será que coloquei errado? Obrigado pela ajuda! ^^

Comment: Então use o CSS adicionando uma classe no elemento e adicionando o CSS

Comment: Isso não funciona

Comment: :/ realmente, mas obrigado por tentar ajudar. ^^/